# Duplicated String when storing .xml file

Tags: loops, textbox, append

I have the following problem: The code runs well, but the problem is that is the string is duplicated when storing the data into a .xml File.

```
 StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            data.Append(inicio);
            data.Append(" ");

          TextBox[]boxesc = {c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17,c18,c19,c20};
          TextBox[] boxesu = { u1, u2, u3, u4, u5, u6, u7, u8, u9, u10, u11, u12, u13, u14, u15, u16, u17, u18, u19, u20 };
          TextBox[] boxesn = { n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9, n10, n11, n12, n13, n14, n15, n16, n17, n18, n19, n20 };
          TextBox[] boxesd = { d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8, d9, d10, d11, d12, d13, d14, d15, d16, d17, d18, d19, d20 };
          TextBox[] boxesv = { v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, v11, v12, v13, v14, v15, v16, v17, v18, v19, v20 };
          TextBox[] boxesi = { i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9, i10, i11, i12, i13, i14, i15, i16, i17, i18, i19, i20 };
       //foreach (var tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    foreach (var text in boxesc )
    {
        if (text.Text != string.Empty)
        {
         for (int i = 0; i < boxesc.Length; i++)
         { 

             data.Append(boxesc[i].Text);
             data.Append(boxesu[i].Text);
             data.Append(boxesn[i].Text);
             data.Append(boxesd[i].Text);
             data.Append(boxesv[i].Text);
             data.Append(boxesi[i].Text);

         }
        }
    }
    string send = Convert.ToString(data);
 Result: 
 1|pz|001|desc1|10|10|2|can|002|desc2|15|30|
 1|pz|001|desc1|10|10|2|can|002|desc2|15|30|
```

Comment: I am developing a Billing System,
And I want to add different Concepts according to the Concepts that the user specifies in the Bill Form

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing the first for each loop